# Django auth: How to get user data?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I´m trying to develop an app which when user requests will give his additional details only if he is logged-in
I am using Django-Rest-Framework. I´m able to log in, get token, but how can I retrieve additional User data?

```
class BasicUserInfo(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_index=True)

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(BasicUserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phoneNo = PhoneField(default="")
```

So basically if user requests with GET API endpoint I want to send only that user's phone number

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How to access the data, or how to limit the access? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is absolutely no point to your BasicUserInfo class, particularly as AbstractUser already has an email field. Why don't you just use the standard User model directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether user is logged in or not by `request.user.is_authenticated()` and `request.user` will return the current logged in user (if use is logged in otherwise it will return object of AnonymousUser class)

Your get method will look like

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        data['phone_number'] = request.user.userinfo_set.first().phoneNo

    return response.Response(data)
```